# Create aliases on host during vagrant up using vagrant-triggers

Tags: vagrant

Hoping someone can help me out here.

I am wanting to create aliases on my local machine (host) when running `vagrant up`. Through my search for *vagrant run command on host*, I came across the [`vagrant-triggers`](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) plugin. From the surface it appears to do exactly what I want (executing a script/command on the host machine during the vagrant provisioning process), however I have not been able to get it working successfully.

Below is my example code. I don't receive any errors, but the aliases are not available on the host.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Your existing Vagrant configuration
  ...

  # start vagrant-triggers example code
  {
    :up => [
      'alias runscript="$(PWD)/script"',
      'alias runscript2="$(PWD)/script2"'
    ],
    [:halt, :destroy] => [
      'unalias runscript',
      'unalias runscript2'
    ]
  }.each do |trigger, commands|
    config.trigger.after trigger, :stdout => true do
      commands.each do |command|
        run command
      end
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands are executed in a subshell of the `vagrant` process, and aliases are only available for that subshell, not for any of the parent processes. So you would need to for example write helper scripts to a directory that you put in the `PATH`.